# When Build Flink on windows, mvn directory-maven-plugin error occurred

Tags: maven, apache-flink

When I build Flink on a Windows laptop, I get an error, but when I build flink on a MAC, it works

command:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dfast
```

result:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.commonjava.maven.plugins:directory-maven-plugin:0.1:highest-basedir (directories) on project flink-parent: Cannot find a single highest directory for this project set. First two candidates directories don't share a common root. -> [Help 1]
```

What is the reason for this? thank you

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by removing the directory-maven-plugin plugin in pom.xml and adding a property called rootDir in the properties section, which is the root directory of the current flink project.

```
<properties>
    <rootDir>D:\IdeaProjects\flink</rootDir>
    ******
</properties>
```

remove this plugin :

```
        <!-- generate configuration docs -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.commonjava.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>directory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>directories</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>highest-basedir</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <property>rootDir</property>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```